# How do I change or replace all instances of a character in a text file to a newline/line break/EOL in Notepad2 or Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, newlines

I tried [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html)'s 'Replace Text' function, but I don't know what to put in the 'Replace with' field.

The OS I'm using is Windows 7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Notepad2**
Search mode: Regular expression search
Replace with: \r\n

**Notepad++**
Search mode: Extended (or Regular expression)
Replace with : \r\n

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Know if this can also be done with Notepad2?

Comment: Sorry, @galacticninja - I don't use Notepad2, but I expect there's something similar in its search facility: I think you tick the box for "Regular expression".

Comment: Yes: as I thought, *Regular expression search* does the job in Notepad2. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I replaced '-' with just the line return (\r) without the extra (empty) line (\n) to get each parameter (50) on its own line.