# How to find and replace new line in Notepad ++

Tags: notepad++

I use `\n`, but the new line is not replaced.

I supposed the new lines contain 2 characters, `\n` and `\l`, but searching and replacing `\l` yields to no results as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/294893/how-do-i-change-or-replace-all-instances-of-a-character-in-a-text-file-to-a-newl

Comment: @nixda This question is about *looking for newlines*, the other is about *inserting newlines*.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Are you sure you enabled search-mode "extended"?

By the way, what kind of ["new line"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) depends on the system you are working on. On Windows you might try and search for `\r\n`

[image]

Comment: \l -> matched lowercase letters (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_character_classes)

Comment: \r is indeed the issue

Comment: how do you show the CR LF thingy anyway?

Comment: @JimThio `Menu Bar » View » Show symbol » Show end of line`