# how to transpose 1XN into NX1 in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

How to convert, in  windows, the following

```
5.89813e-01  5.38450e-01  4.28379e-01  2.72359e-01
```

into

```
5.89813e-01
5.38450e-01
4.28379e-01
2.72359e-01
```

There appears to be 2 spaces between each number.

Comment: Use Replace and select Extended at the bottom-left under Search Mode.  Put 2 spaces in the Find What box and \n or \r\n (whichever for your OS) in the Replace With box.

Comment: Do the reverse of this https://superuser.com/questions/542719/how-to-find-and-replace-new-line-in-notepad

Comment: doesnt work in windows. It finds the space but it doesnt actully return it to the new line.

Comment: Works for me.  Find what: `[2 spaces]`.  Replace with: `\n`.  Did you select Extended for search mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\h+`
- Replace with: `\n` or `\r\n` depending on platform
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\h+         # 1 or more horizontal spaces
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]